# Dynamic query with Jpa Specification

Tags: spring-data-jpa, specifications

I recently worked with Jpa Specification in Spring boot project i want to understand the difference between  javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate and Predicate the functional interface also what is the Expression Type, the Join Type, the Path Type and why in the and of the method toPredicate we return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]))

try to understand some Knowledge about Specification